# Graduate Career Advice - Re-applying to Stronger Programs Next Cycle After Initial Acceptances

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am a senior undergrad going into a Ph.D. this fall in the field of polymers/chemical engineering, and while I have already gotten accepted into strong programs in that field, I have this lingering regret that I should have applied to higher-ranked programs during my initial application cycle. I only applied to a few select schools (including my undergrad institution), and gotten into strong programs for polymers/soft matter.

However, I severely undercut myself due to self-doubt about my application strength when I applied; I had suffered a hit in my coursework grades during my junior year due to extenuating medical circumstances, but all other semesters were absolutely unblemished (everything was also explained in my application).

Furthermore, I believe that other areas of my application were relatively strong, including extensive semester and summer research, multiple semesters of TA experience, pertinent industry internships, as well as positive encouragement and guidance from all of my professors to pursue graduate school.

Unfortunately, my train of thought while applying was that the admissions committees for "top programs" in the field would see my junior year grades and cut me then and there without even taking a look at the rest of my application.

I suppose that this logic, in hindsight, did not make any sense, as I've been accepted into strong programs, however, I sort of wish that I applied to more "reach" programs, and just aimed one tiny step higher than I had in my original list of schools. The regret of not even attempting to apply for those higher programs is more stressful than getting rejected by all of them (because I at least tried), there's always that "what-if" question mark that periodically comes around when I think about the future.

Would it be worth it to apply for those higher programs this fall again, or should I just move on from this thought and attend my current choices? Note that my rationale behind another round of applications, but to the top-ranked programs in this field (University of Minnesota, Delaware, UT Austin), is that these universities have far larger resources, alumni networks, and more professors working in my specific subfields of interest.

Answer (score 2):

I will go ahead and say **no**, don't apply again! Starting a Ph.D. is more about your work and mentor than the program's prestige. Achievements, research quality, and the guidance of your advisor will outweigh the university's rank in the long run. Your success depends on conducting significant research, publishing, and engaging in academia, not just on the institution's name.

Reapplying to other programs could unnecessarily delay your academic journey. Utilize the resources and opportunities of the programs you've been accepted to. Complete the coursework, pass all required examinations, and keep moving forward! The impact of your research and the mentors you choose are more critical to your future in academia or industry than the program's prestige. Focus on making the most of your current opportunities and setting a strong foundation for your career rather than wasting another year of your life, time, and resources (financial, mental, etc.) in reapplying!

Comment: Excellent answer. There are excellent advisors almost everywhere. Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good.